# Opening a Popup or ActionSheet on Button of TabViewController

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, nib, nstabviewcontroller

i am using TabViewController as my base landing view for application.From one of the tabs (which is named as "more") i want to open a popup or Action sheet showing more option (without opening any view).i tried changing the relationship segue but doesn't found any valid wayaround.Right now i am opening a blank view on MORE tab.Check image for better idea.

the popupview i want to open on "more" is a xib and below is the code i am using this code for opening it.

```
 let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: PopUpViewControllerSwift.self)
    self.popViewController = PopUpViewControllerSwift(nibName: "MorePopup", bundle: bundle)
    self.popViewController.showInView(self.view,animated: true)
```

where PopUPViewController is the popup class   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgy3I.png)